# How can I map two parents to the same child using @OneToOne and @MapsId

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following problem: two parents entities can have the same type of child entity (but not the same child). I want to map both of relations using `@MapsId` and `@OneToOne`. The child is optional in both cases and can not exist without parent. The problem is that I am getting `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property`  when I try to create an instance of one of the parents.

This is the code:

first parent entity

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "first_parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class FirstParent {

@Id
private UUID id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "firstParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Child child;

protected FirstParent(Child child) {
 this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
 setChild(child);
}

private void setChild(@Nullable Child child) {
  this.child = child;

  if (child != null) {
   child.setId(id);
   child.setFirstParent(this);
  }
 }
}
```

second parent entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "second_parent")
@Inheritence(strategy = InheritenceType.JOINED)
public abstract class SecondParent {

@Id
private UUID id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "secondParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Child child;

protected SecondParent(Child child) {
  this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
  setChild(child);
 }

private void setChild(@Nullable Child child) {
  this.child = child;

  if (child != null) {
   child.setId(id);
   child.setSecondParent(this);
  }
 }
}
```

child entity:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

@Id
private UUID id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private FirstParent firstParent;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private SecondParent secondParent;

}
```

The problem is that every time when I am creating a `firstParent` instance, I am getting the following execption:
`org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [.....Child.secondParent]`

This is indicating me that hibernate attempts to assign the id also for the `secondParent` even if it shouldn't do that, should do this only for the child entity.

Interesting is, that when I am creating an instance of `firstParent`, the above mentioned exception does not occures.

What am I doing wrong and how can I map this properly?

Comment: Okay, so as far as I understand `@MapsId`, you are currently trying to force 2 separate identifiers on the child id. Example: `FirstParent` has id `123` and `SecondParent` has id `abc`. Which id should `Child` now have?

Comment: `FirstParent` and `SecondParent` can not have the same `Child`. So, the `FirstParent` (with id `123`) will have the `Child` with id `123`; and the `SecondParent` (with id `abc`) will have the `Child` with id `abc`

Comment: But one child should have a `FirstParent` as well as a `SecondParent` at the same time as per your mapping

Comment: Ok, than the mappings are wrong. `FirstParent` and `SecondParent` are not related, they can just a `Child` (optional). How should I map this?

Comment: Do you need a reference from child to parent?

Comment: I only need to be able to cascade all the operations from parent to child

Comment: Then it should be enough to remove both `@OneToOne` from `Child` class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248969/discussion-between-air-and-xtremebaumer).